# AnyLogic assembler as a gateway

Tags: java, anylogic

Good morning,
I'm new on AnyLogic platform and I have started to study it because I want to use it to map the business processes of the company. I've plan to use the Process Model Library of the tool to model the different departments with the aim to study how are now implemented the information flows between departments.

My diagram will be composed by ''source'' elements and different ''assembler''  elements and I would like that the last ones (the assemblers) work as gateways. I enclose a simple diagram to illustrate better the situation [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dasUu.png).

Suppose that ''sourceA'' and ''sourceB'' (placed in different departments) generate two different documents implemented with two custom agents (e.g. agents generated from ''sourceA'' have an ''orderID'' parameter and agents generated from ''sourceB'' have a ''qualityCheckID'' parameter) that are conveyed on the respective queues before reach the assembler component (placed in a different department). The queues, with an high probability are not aligned during the simulation (queue[10] = agent.orderID is set to 10 and queue[10] = agent.qualityIDCheck is set to 9) becuase the departments are not synchronized. I would like that the assembler work as a gateway so it waits for agents that have ''orderID'' equals to ''qualityCheckID'' (that means that the products on a specific order have been validated by the quality department).

Reading the documentation I saw that the agents reach the assembler port when it is free and wait in the queue otherwise. Due to the asynchronization may happen that in the assembler ports are present agents that not have orderID equals to qualityCheckID and in this case I don't want that the assembler's output will be produced. May happen that the necessary agent is in the queue and not in the port so the "assembler" have to search inside the queues to find if the corrisponding agent is present and if it is remove it from the queue (substitute the wrong agent in the port bringing this last one in the queue and produce the output)

Someone can help me to understand how this scenario can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning Andrea.

There are some alternatives to this. 
If both the IDs are generated incrementally (1, 2, 3, ...., N) you can use a Match block and it will synchronize your flow. Plus, you can remove your queue elements as this block already has queues incorporated.

However, if the IDs are generated randomly, you might need to do some kind of a work around and use Java code and functions. 
What I would do would be the following:

Instead of using a **Queue** (which sends the agents out as soon as the next block is available) I would use the **Wait** block (which is pretty much a **Queue** but does not order elements nor does it send the agents out until you want it. Read the description on AnyLogic and it will be clear).

Whenever an agent enter a **Wait** Block I would add it to a **LinkedHashMap** or **HashMap** collection with an Integer (or the type of your order parameter) key and Agent value (one for each Wait Block). This would allow easier information access (rather than searching through the entire Wait contents every time I wanted to check if a specific agent was there). 
The next step would be to simply check if on the other Wait Block(s) there are the elements I need to perform the assembly task. If so, free them all (and the current agent).

The code is as follows:

On Enter:

```
WaitBlockHashMap.put(agent.orderID, agent)
if (WaitBlockHashMap2.get(agent.orderID)!=null) { //if the matching element 
                                                  //is on the other Wait Block
    self.free(agent);
    WaitBlock2.free(WaitBlockHashMap2.get(agent.orderID));
}
```

or

```
WaitBlockHashMap.put(agent.qualityCheckID, agent)
if (WaitBlockHashMap2.get(agent.qualityCheckID)!=null) { //if the matching element 
                                                         //is on the other Wait Block
    self.free(agent);
    WaitBlock2.free(WaitBlockHashMap2.get(agent.qualityCheckID));
}
```

Depending on the type of agent in that **Wait** Block.

I do hope this is helpful,
Luís

Comment: Thanks for your help.

So if I understood correctly I'm replacing all **queues**, before an **assembler** element, with as many **wait** blocks (one for each necessary object) and then I'll do the check whenever a new agent enters in one of the **wait** blocks and then I'll free all the necessary object when the match succedeed.

P.S. Can you suggest to me a text or a web tutorial on which I can learn some basics in program blocks? (I already know the Java language)

Comment: Yes, I think you've understood the concept.
Program blocks? You mean, how to use the Anylogic blocks? When I said "Wait Block" I was referring to the Wait element from the Process Modelling Library!

Comment: With ''program block'' I mean some tutorial on how to code in the event handlers

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any tutorial that focus on that. However, anylogic help is very useful. Also, you can do the "Anylogic in three days" PDF which comes with Anylogic and to which you can access through the Welcome Tab.

Comment: In your code who owns the WaitBlockHashMap? It is a local class variable? If yes how and where I create local class variables?

Comment: The hashMap is a collection owned by the environment agent. Normally, it will be the Main agent.

Comment: It is possible to have a hashMap as a class variable of a wait block?

Comment: I believe not as you cannot edit native Anylogic library elements (at least, as far as I know!)

Comment: So, if my network is complex (many departments with many gateways) where I place the HashMap used by the block elements?

Comment: I have to create a lot of HashMap in the onStartup event handler of the main agent?

Comment: You either place them in the Main agent (where you develop your model) and you will need to create one for each department. 
However, if you are comfortable with Anylogic, you can create an Agent that will be your department. In Anylogic you can create agents that contain flowcharts with PML elements. You can also add collections (as your hashmap) to it. You program it with functions or whatever you find useful and needed. Then, you just drag the agent to the Main and it will have the collection incorporated. However, this will be hard if you are not confortable with Anylogic.

Comment: Later I'll probably right a post on how to create custom Blocks here on StackOverflow.